# How do I set a chat icon to a telegram bot?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a 'Bot' class extending the 'TelegramLongPollingBot' and such a void for setting a bot icon:

```
private void setChatIcon() {
    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    URL url = loader.getResource("/sky.jpg");
    assert url != null;
    File file = new File(url.getPath());
    SetChatPhoto setChatPhoto = new SetChatPhoto();
    try {
        execute(setChatPhoto.setPhoto(file));
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where should I call it and are therea any mistakes in my code?

Comment: Do you want to change the icon ofter or just one time?

Comment: I only need to set it one time.

Comment: I know this will work when you talk to @BotFather and use the /setuserpic command. So, I don't have a programmatical solution.

Comment: @jmizv thanks. That was much easeier than i thouht)